# Is "why isn't my fpga blinking an LED" on topic here?

Tags: discussion

I've bought an FPGA, written some verilog to blink an LED, I've flashed the FPGA and it "doesn't work".

So my question is basically "why don't I see any blinking? Where is the bug and how do I fix it"

Now, if I describe what I've tried to debug my work, explain how my source is built, etc, how I'm flashing it, is the question on-topic here?

[This is the question I ended up posting](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/496495/why-isnt-my-led-blinking?noredirect=1#comment1265452_496495).

Comment: Who said it wasn't on-topic? I didn't see any close votes. You may have gotten the down vote because you didn't put all of the necessary information in the question itself.

Comment: @Elliot I don't know that anyone said that. I just wanted to make sure before I posted the question.

Comment: A link to the question would be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I describe what I've tried to debug my work, explain how my source is built, etc, how I'm flashing it, is the question on-topic here?

If you do all that, then yes, absolutely. But most people would only dump your *first* sentence here and expect everyone to guess wildly, which would be a bad question.

Answer (score 1):

FPGA, Verilog (or any other HDL) and LEDs are all on-topic here, as are questions about trouble-shooting electronics.

You are however assumed to have sufficient electronics knowledge to perform some basic trouble-shooting yourself when prompted. At least basic stuff like hooking up a multimeter to measure supply voltage, pin output voltage and LED polarity.

The more details and trouble-shooting efforts you can put in the question, the better. Include source code and/or schematic and/or links to datasheets in the question, if they are relevant.